# Loop through variables by name objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

can I loop through variables by it's name??

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *img1;
IBOutlet UIImageView *img2;
IBOutlet UIImageView *img3;
IBOutlet UIImageView *img4;
IBOutlet UIImageView *img5;
IBOutlet UIImageView *img6;
IBOutlet UIImageView *img7;
IBOutlet UIImageView *img8;

//then
for(int i = 1; i<=8;i++){
   img+i = nil; 
}
```

I know how to loop via tag, but is it posible to do it like this in objective C ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly, but you can add them to a temporary array or use `IBOutletCollection`

Answer (score 1):

just for the record, you can do this (but dont do it, use the previous answer)

```
for(int i = 1; i<=8;i++){
    SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"setImg%d:", i]);
    [self performSelector:sel withObject:nil];
}
```

Comment: interesting !! thanks Ultrakorne, I end up using:                     IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) NSArray *imgs;                      this is the best thing I've found or looping via Img tag.